# Entity Core Dynamic LINQ LIKE function not found

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, dynamic-linq-core

I am trying to use the ZZZ Dynamic LINQ library in my .net core project using examples from their website and I am bumping into issues. Using their own JS fiddle the same issues occur, essentially it seems to be looking on the entity for the DynamicFunctions.Like function when it evaluates the query string.

I am constructing my query like this

```
 ret += "DynamicFunctions.Like(" + prop.Name + ", @0)";
```

inside of a loop and the exception I receive at runtime is

```
Unhandled exception. No property or field 'DynamicFunctions' exists in type 'Log'
```

You can see the issue occur in their examples here https://dotnetfiddle.net/dy4vkE

Has there been a change to this API? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please post this in their github repository. It's clearly a bug.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of others who hit this bug, this has now been logged as [an issue in the relevant github repo](https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/issues/396).

[This link](https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/blob/master/src-console/ConsoleAppEF2.1.1/Program.cs#L130) to a working code sample is also provided in the issue.